# NetLogo:coloring the part of the world

Tags: colors, netlogo

I'm really new at programming in NetLogo and i need a little help. I need to write the procedure that will paint edge border of the world in violet.
Also i need to write the procedure that will paint 15 random fields in the world in violet colour (not counting allready exsisting walls).

Here is the picture how it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Gs7.jpg

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  ; paint the world's border:
  ask patches with [ 
    pxcor = min-pxcor or
    pxcor = max-pxcor or
    pycor = min-pycor or
    pycor = max-pycor 
  ]
  [ 
    set pcolor violet 
  ]
  ; paint 15 not-yet-painted patches:
  ask n-of 15 patches with [ pcolor != violet ] [
    set pcolor violet
  ]
end
```